# How to get raw binary from hash function in ColdFusion 9?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, sha

In ColdFusion 9, I am hashing a string like so: `hash("bob", "SHA1")`, I need it to return binary instead of a hex string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you know the hashed string is in hex, simply decode it with the aptly named [binaryDecode()](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/BinaryDecode) function.

```
hashedString = hash("bob", "SHA1");
binaryData = binaryDecode(hashedString , "Hex");
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this the sort of thing yer after?

```
<cfscript>
s = "G'day World";
hash1 = hash(s, "SHA-1");
bin = binaryDecode(hash1, "hex");
hash2 = binaryEncode(bin, "hex");

writeDump(variables);
</cfscript>
```

[image: output of code]

Docs:

- [`BinaryDecode()`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/BinaryDecode)
- [`BinaryEncode()`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/BinaryEncode)

Comment: Adam - Not sure if SO sends notifications once a post is deleted, but I posted an explanation beneath Matt's (now deleted) answer. In short, the problem was not just that using `toBase64/toBinary()` is more involved, it also returns the wrong result. So the first two answers were incorrect. That is why I promoted my earlier comment to an answer ;-)